# Representation of objects

Tags: python, django, class

Sometimes we have to represent our objects of classes with it's attributes. Mostly we use

```
def __str__
```

for string representation which generally return characters.
But I have a class with no attribute that has characters. I wanted to represent that with the only attribute which is a DecimalField. Please help me to get the right syntax to represent my objects.

Comment: You would still use `__str__`, convert decimal to string and return that with some additional identifier i,e what's that decimal field is for: `return 'My Value: {}'.format(self.my_decimal_field)`

Comment: The attribute I wanted to represent is:
    average = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
Please can you show me how to write syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__str__` should always return a string. What you could do is following:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Average: {}'.format(self.average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value of the `DecimalField` to `string`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.average)
```

or alternatively, if you have more complex values, you could use the method `to_eng_string`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.average.to_eng_string
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) says:

> Convert to a string, using engineering notation if an exponent is
>   needed.
>
> Engineering notation has an exponent which is a multiple of 3. This
>   can leave up to 3 digits to the left of the decimal place and may
>   require the addition of either one or two trailing zeros.
>
> For example, this converts Decimal('123E+1') to Decimal('1.23E+3').